# How to create term frequency matrix for multiple text files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix

I have the following code for a total of four text files all containing a few different keywords. They are called test1.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt and test4.txt. I want to transform it into a matrix/list of lists. I have the following code.

```
temp = [''] + list(sample_collection)
values = list(sample_collection['test1.txt'])

sample_collection = [temp] + [[x] + [v.get(x, 0) for v in sample_collection.values()] for x in values]
```

However, I want to modify it to include not only the keywords from test1, but all other unique keywords from the other files. I have no clue how to do so. Is there a way to do so with that piece of code?

expected output:

```
[['', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt'],
['apple', 1, 0, 2, 1],
['banana', 1, 1, 1, 1],
['lemon', 1, 1, 0, 0],
['grape', 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: I would use `sklearn` framework.

Comment: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `sklearn` framework.

It isn't a part of python base packages, so you will need to install it (`pip install sklearn`).

than, import the `CountVectorizer`:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
```

read you files and store them in a list.
let's say you will call it `my_corpus`. now  you have a list named `my_corpus` with 4 members.

just use:

```
vectorizer =  CountVectorizer()    
matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(my_corpus)
```

Alternativly, if you wouldn't like to use a oter packages, just do:
corpus = ["I like dogs", "I like cats", "cats like milk", "You likes me"]
token_corpus = [s.split() for s in corpus]

```
vocabulary = {}                                                                      
for i, f in enumerate(token_corpus):                                                 
    for t in f:                                                                      
        if t not in vocabulary:                                                      
             vocabulary[t] = [0]*len(corpus)                                         
        vocabulary[t][i]+=1                                                          

vocabulary
{'I': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'like': [1, 1, 1, 0], 'dogs': [1, 0, 0, 0], 'cats': [0, 1, 1, 0], 'milk': [0, 0, 1, 0], 'You': [0, 0, 0, 1], 'likes': [0, 0, 0, 1], 'me': [0, 0, 0, 1]}
```

if you want to save it in a list just use:

```
list(map(list, vocabulary.items()))
[['I', [1, 1, 0, 0]], ['like', [1, 1, 1, 0]], ['dogs', [1, 0, 0, 0]], ['cats', [0, 1, 1, 0]], ['milk', [0, 0, 1, 0]], ['You', [0, 0, 0, 1]], ['likes', [0, 0, 0, 1]], ['me', [0, 0, 0, 1]]]
```

Comment: Thank you! However, is there a way to do it without external libraries?